# Export "Local" Excel File to a SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server

I want to import data from excel to SQL SERVER using queries,not by using wizard. I tried this query

```
Select PerCode,'1395/01',Day1,Day2,Day3,Day4,Day5,...,Day30,Day31
From OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\TimeSheet.xls;',
                'SELECT PerCode,Day1,Day2,Day3,Day4,Day5,...,Day30,Day31 FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

The important point is, I can use a local Path on a client, not on server.
Is there any way?

Comment: You can make a shared folder on a client side and use its network path on server side. F.e. I make shared folder on my computer like `\\MyComp\Shared` and I can use this on server side to access file.

Comment: Thank you GORF1. But it fordec me to know the IP of the client.